# "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" - but no duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm converting an app from native mysqli calls to PDO.  Running into an error when attempting to insert a row into a table with a foreign key constraint.

**Note:** this is a simplified test case and should not be copy/pasted into a production environment.

**Info** PHP 5.3, MySQL 5.4

First, here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `z_one` (
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name_last` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_first` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateadded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `z_one` VALUES (1,'Khan','Ghengis','2014-12-17 10:43:01');

CREATE TABLE `z_many` (
  `order_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateadded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  KEY `order_index` (`customer_id`,`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `z_many_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `z_one` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Or if you prefer,

```
mysql> describe z_one;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| customer_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name_last   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name_first  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dateadded   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> describe z_many;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| order_id    | varchar(15)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| customer_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dateadded   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Next, here is the query:

```
    $order_id = '22BD24';
    $customer_id = 1;

    try 
    {
        $q = "
            INSERT INTO 
                z_many 
                (
                    order_id,
                    customer_id,
                    dateadded
                )
            VALUES 
                (
                    :order_id,
                    :customer_id,
                    NOW()
                )
        ";
        $stmt = $dbx_pdo->prepare($q);
        $stmt->bindValue(':order_id', $order_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':customer_id', $customer_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch(PDOException $err) {
        // test case only.  do not echo sql errors to end users.
        echo $err->getMessage();
    }
```

This results in the following PDO error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '22BD24' for key 'PRIMARY'

The same query works fine when handled by `mysqli`.  Why is PDO rejecting the INSERT with a 'duplicate entry' message when there aren't any duplicates found?

Comment: I doin't know much about PDO, but this `KEY "order_index" ("customer_id","order_id")` looks like you are creating a key which would only allow a single order per customer. I may be wrong though because I know nothing about the PDO syntax or operators.

Comment: Your check is redundant. Apart from choosing bad data types for primary keys, you don't have to check whether an order with specific id exists. You can just insert. If the insert fails, you check whether it failed because of integrity constraint violation which means the record with that PK exists.

Comment: @Pow-lan That's SQL DDL, it has nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: Nevermind the check - it is muddying the waters here.   I will delete it from the question.

Comment: @Air Thomas, I figured that out right after I posted the comment. I think that instance of `KEY` needs to change to `INDEX` based on the name of the constraint

Comment: @NB - there are zero rows in the z_many table in this example.   It is an empty table and I am attempting to insert the very first row.

Comment: @Pow-lan `KEY` and `INDEX` are synonyms in MySQL. In any case, it's not a *unique* constraint so it's unlikely to be related to this error.

Comment: @acoder Have you checked the table using the CLI or phpMyAdmin to make sure the row hasn't been inserted after you see the error message? I haven't been able to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @AirThomas - actually, I'm showing that the row IS being inserted!

Comment: @acoder So, when you truncate the table, and load the page a single time, you get an error and you also see the row is inserted? Or is it possible you simply refreshed the page?

Comment: 1) `truncate z_many;`  2) refresh page (to load row as above).  3) Error is produced.  4) Row was inserted.   Page is not loading twice - just a static script that contains no meta refresh or header calls.

Comment: Run the code outside of the webserver and/or add some debug output (to a logfile, not `echo` etc). I'm pretty sure the insert is executed twice.

Comment: Since this is so weird - and *just* to make sure your script isn't being executed twice - put an `echo "success!";` after your `$stmt->execute();`.  If it still only displays the code in your catch then you can be 100% sure that code is only executing once and continue from there.  And best to run it from the command line as suggested by Ulrich

Comment: So I wanted to test this and copied the sql to create a table, ran it in phpmyadmin and copied the code exactly. Added a line to create a new pdo connection and everything else was copy/paste exactly the same. Ran the page and it created a row as expected with no error. Refreshed and got the same integrity constraint error as expected. This is php 5.4.12 and mysql 5.6. So like most everyone else, I would go back to checking that this isn't getting ran more than once. Is the page being included in another script? Is this in a function or being called from a framework?

Comment: most probably this is executed twice not from the sql part but from php part. Not all relevant code is shown in this example. a simple on duplicate key update would solve this. Otherwise check all your php code, where this part you provided is written, again.

Comment: Did you try to execute the script that you gave here from cli? You are obviously inserting it twice. Probably you are testing more complex code sample which has some broken logic. Try to set up a breakpoint before calling `$stmt->execute()` and at this point go to your DB and look if it already has this row inserted. If not, try to execute `$dbx_pdo->commit();` at this point in order to commit all possibly opened transactions and check you DB again. (with xdebug you can execute your code at any point when execution of the script is paused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since not all code is available (from php side) just in case your query is in some sort of loop the quickest (and perhaps partly) solution to this is the following:

```
$order_id = '22BD24';
$customer_id = 1;

try {
    $q = "INSERT INTO `z_many` (`order_id`,`customer_id`,`dateadded`)
        VALUES (:order_id,:customer_id,NOW())
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `dateadded`=NOW()";

    $stmt = $dbx_pdo->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bindValue(':order_id', $order_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':customer_id', $customer_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $err) {

    // test case only.  do not echo sql errors to end users.
    echo $err->getMessage();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've copied the SQL schema you provided on my mysql DB and added script code, but with PDO initialization at the start:
`$dbx_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test12;charset=utf8','root','');`

.. and it **worked fine**, but my setup is php 5.5.9 and mysql 5.6.16

So I think your code executes twice and maybe its inside of a transaction, so you get rollback. Need to know more context

Comment: hm, I will need to add more debug output to the log file then.  I'm seeing no evidence that this page could possibly reload, but I will find out and update.

Answer (score 1):

Please REMOVE default for primary key column. Also use the construction

```
INSERT INTO (`field1`, `field2`, `...`) values (val1, val2, val3);
```

If you tell what default value is for inserts - some mysql versions can see errors when inserting. Thats why you should use auto-increment or dont use default value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark. I use PDO with ORACLE PL/SQL only with bindParam(). And have a look at the forth parameter `,15` if it is a `PARAM_STR` value. So try this, hope it helps.

```
   $stmt->bindParam(':order_id', $order_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
   $stmt->bindParam(':customer_id', $customer_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This 15 descibes the (bufffer-)length from order_id in your table.