# PDO "Integrity constraint violation - Duplicate entry", but no duplicates in table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting "Duplicate entry" on an insert query that worked fine with the old mysqli functions.  Once I converted to PDO, the same insert statement breaks.

Here's the sample SQL data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lookup_codes` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `lookup_codes` (`id`, `code`) VALUES
(1, 'AR'),
(1, 'CN'),
(1, 'OA'),
(4, 'AR'),
(4, 'OA');
```

And here is the example php/pdo code.  *(This is not a code critique request - just trying to boil down a problem to a simple example, do not use this code in production, yada yada).*

```
    // posted data from user
    $id = 2;
    $arr_codes = array('AR','CN');

    // make sure existing rows do not exist
    try
    {
        $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lookup_codes WHERE id=:id";
        if ($dbg) { echo "<p>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lookup_codes WHERE id=$id<br>";}
        $stmt = $dbx_pdo->prepare($q);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        list($count_rows) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); $stmt->closeCursor();

        if ($count_rows>0)
        {
            try
            {
                $q = "DELETE FROM lookup_codes WHERE id=:id";
                if ($dbg) { echo "<p>DELETE FROM lookup_codes WHERE id=$id<br>";}
                $stmt = $dbx_pdo->prepare($q);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->closeCursor();

            } catch(PDOException $err) {
                echo $err->getMessage());
                exit;
            }

        }

    } catch(PDOException $err) {
        echo $err->getMessage());
        exit;
    }



    // set up prepared statement based on posted data
    foreach ($arr_codes as $code)
    {
        $arr_ip[] = array(
            'id'    => $id,
            'code'  => $code,
        );
    }
    $txt_prepared = join(',', array_fill(0, count($arr_ip), '( ?, ?)'));

    // try inserting
    try 
    {
        $q = "INSERT INTO lookup_codes (id, code) VALUES $txt_prepared";
        $stmt = $dbx_pdo->prepare($q);
        $cb = 1;
        foreach ($arr_ip as $rip)
        {
            $id = $rip['id'];
            $code   = $rip['code'];

            $stmt->bindParam($cb++, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam($cb++, $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if ($dbg) { echo "<b>Binding</b> ($id, $code)<br>";}
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

    } catch(PDOException $err) {
        echo $err->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
```

That's all there is on my test script.  No header or meta redirects.. just a single run of code here.

The example above results in:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry '2-CN' for key 'PRIMARY'

Note that it reports back duplicate on the *second* submitted code.

The same `INSERT` works just fine when using `mysqli_query()`.  There are no errors written to the error log.

What is going on here?

Comment: No duplicates in the db because it prevented you from inserting the duplicate. The error says it all. You already have '2','CN' in the db and tried to insert it again. Thus, a primary key constraint error. If it worked with `mysqli_` its because you didn't have the primary key on the table when you were using `mysqli_`.

Comment: Did you build the database and run the script above?  Because I can tell you did not.  Try testing the script as it is listed above to see why your response is incorrect.

Comment: @developerwjk you may also look at the selected answer to discover why your comment is off the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you are binding on your insert query. You need to change `$stmt->bindParam` to `$stmt->bindValue`. bindParam takes a variable by reference so on each iteration of your loop as you change the value of $id and $code you are changing the value that was bound. bindValue will take a copy of the value from the variable and bind that instead.

Comment: I concur, the values from `bindParam` are evaluated at the time `execute` is called. The values are *not* evaluated when `bindParam` is called. This is it.

Comment: @Jonathan-kuhn if you are still monitoring, could you take a quick gander at this similar unresolved issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529774/integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-but-no-duplicate-rows

Comment: @acoder I looked it over real quick and didn't see anything out of the ordinary that looked wrong. I would be willing to say that the query is not running multiple times as the one guy suggests or else you would end up with both, one row from the first run and the error from the second (unless you are turning autocommit off, running this in a transaction and the error is rolling back the queries or they never get committed because the error exits). I'm not somewhere that I can test the code for now and I'll check it out in a few hours when I get home if no one has helped.

Comment: @acoder I would suggest removing the code from any sort of framework if there is one, add just the basics to the page like connecting to mysql and run the script by loading the url directly. You could also echo out a message (or write message to file) before running the query to see if it is actually being called more than once (couldn't hurt). Or query all rows out of the table and dump the results to file/echo to see what exists before doing the insert.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - code is vanilla PHP and not far off from the example shown.